# Tabs widget from Elementor is not showing the content in it to users. But at admin side it is working fine

Tags: widgets

As you can see in attached screenshot it is just showing the title name of tabs nothing else. By clicking on the titles nothing it will do. So, This is how users having experience. It is working and showing perfect from admin view.

Any solution?[image]

Comment: I am not seeing an attached screenshot but if it's specific to the Elementor plugin you may get the best help using their support methods.

Comment: Check the SS now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble. If it's working in the admin section, then generally cache / performance optimisations are switched off for admin so that any changes can be seen instantly. If it's not displaying when logged out check the developer console for messages. In my case I had to switch off the 'Defer Render-blocking JS' as scripts were not running with correct dependancies.

Hope this helps

ps if this doesn't work just temporarily diasble cache / performance optimisations to see if that's the cause and then work on each option until you find out whats wrong.